# users below 50 rep can still comment OP

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

I noticed that although when I directly click "comment" under someone else's question I get reminded that my reputation is not high enough yet, if I answer a very short answer it gets converted as a comment on the original post.

I have no opinion whereas it's a good or a bad thing, I just wanted to point it out! If it's voluntary, why not let the users under 50 rep comment the OP's post (if they can do it anyway by posting a short answer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your answer was deleted and turned into a comment by a moderator. As long as your comment is relevant to the question, I'm not going to just delete it to enforce the rules, consider it some slack for the new users. Hopefully the new user will get 50 rep fast enough that it won't happen again.

If you keep posting comments as answers, we will stop turning them into comments and just delete them. And after that, the system will stop accepting answers from you entirely.

Comment: Oh okay I'm very sorry then, I thought that was an automatic feature because it was almost instantaneous! And indeed, thinking that it was automatic I tried it a second time but it didn't work. I'm sorry about that, it won't happen again (hopefully I will have the 50 rep soon enough, because most of the times I have comments to make but no complete and constructed answer)